# RxJS queue http request

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to implement save in a sequence in Angular. So the "save" request should wait until the previous one ends. I have to wait because the previous call returns an ETag.

I was thinking about some "map" in RxJS but I don't know how to wait until the previous one ends.

The main idea is shown in:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-mmcqhy?file=index.ts

Comment: Have a look at `concatMap`. It waits until its previous inner Observable completes.

Comment: `concat` as operator is [deprecated](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/concat). here is a fix for your example : [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-dacbf9). and as Maksim said later in comments, your `save` function must return an observable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be using `concatMap` and then `tap` for the inner logs but it really depends on what behavior you expect.

```
let save = function(arg){
  console.log("start request")
  return ajax('https://httpbin.org/get').pipe(
    tap(...),
  );
}

callQueue$.pipe(
  concatMap(i => save(i)),
)
.subscribe(result => {
  ...
});
```

Your updated demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-13jrrk?file=index.ts

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution with mergeMap concurency - https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-y4nu3i?file=index.ts

```
callQueue$
.pipe(
    mergeMap(result => save(result), 1)
    )
  .subscribe(
    function (data) {
      console.log("finished OK request")
    }
  );
```

Comment: `mergeMap` doesn't wait until the previous inner Observable completes.

Answer (score 0):

I done it the following with concat:

```
import { concat } from 'rxjs/observable/concat';

const source = concat(
    this.myService.saveStuff({ test: 'swag' }), //returns an observable
    this.myService.saveStuff({ test: 'yolo' })
);

source.subscribe(
    response => {
        console.log('Called after each successful save');
    },
    () => {
        console.log('Called when an error happens')
    },
    () => {
        console.log('called when all observables are complete')
    });
```

Comment: But you don't wait until the first save ends.

Comment: maybe  I did something badly but it doesn't work: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-mmcqhy?file=index.ts

Comment: @PiotrStapp, you did few mistakes in your example. 1. Ajax call should not return subscription, but should return stream. 2. Run yards, using concat outside of pipe yo are using it inside of pipe. and few more.  I  fixed you example to work https://stackblitz.com/fork/rxjs?devtoolsheight=60

Comment: @PiotrSrapp `concat` as operator is [deprecated](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/concat). here is a fix for your example : [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-dacbf9). and as Maksim said, your `save` function must return an observable.